# How to access 'properties' in Google Polymer 2?

Tags: javascript, polymer, es6-class, polymer-2.x

In Polymer 1.0, I can declare properties with:

```
properties: {
    salary: {
        type: Number,
        value: 80
    }
}
```

Now in Polymer 2.0 (creating a class), I should write a method like:

```
static get properties() {
    return {
        salary: {
            type: Number,
            value: 80
        }
    }
}
```

But now `this.properties` is `null`. How do I access the `properties` field (not the values of the `properties`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this.properties` attempts to access an instance field (excludes static fields). Since `properties` is a `static` field, you'd have to use either `this.constructor.properties` or `XFoo.properties`.

Example:

```
class XFoo extends Polymer.Element {
  static get properties() { ... }

  constructor() {
    super();

    // this.constructor === XFoo
    console.log('this.constructor.properties', this.constructor.properties);
    console.log('XFoo.properties', XFoo.properties);
  }
}
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/dWbrRM?editors=1010)

Comment: Very good! Obviously, I understand the difference between static and instance fields: my problem was to access the properties in a behavior (in the new approach with class mixins) where I cannot know the name of the (derived) class. To be clear, referring your example, I cannot use your second approach, but the first is perfect! Thank you very much! :-)